# how to use If statement in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I need to calculate one tensor that kind of needs an 'if' statement. Specifically, I need to calculate a tensor and compare it with a constant, then implement different functions.

Here is how I did it(failed):

---

```
num_instances = tf.size(unique_labels)
```

---

```
l_var=tf.cond(tf.less(num_instances,1),true_fn=return_zero(),false_fn=fn())
```

---

*num_instances* the tensor is changing its value as diffrent data is fed into the model during training

Sadly, it didn't work,and the terminal reports

> **'TypeError:** true_fn must be callable. '

you can find my **output** here :

[image: sample output]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us what you are getting as a result, and what you expect as a return. Show us the error that you get, or the undesired result so the community can help you and you can find your answer faster. Also, please don't add images, as they will get lost in time and it's harder to replicate the issue. Please have a read here: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's clearly telling you that `true_fn` is supposed to be a reference to a function, not a value - which it will be now since you're calling the function.

Comment: i just replace 0 with tf.constant(0,tf.float32) , but still it didn't work. So I wonder if it's something else going wrong and it just somehow reports that true_fn is the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'if' statement example for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
@author: myhaspl@myhaspl.com
"""

import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant(11)
y = tf.constant(22)


z = tf.multiply(x, y)
result1 = tf.cond(x > y, lambda: tf.add(x, y), lambda: tf.square(y))
result2 = tf.cond(x < y, lambda: tf.add(x, y), lambda: tf.square(y))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess=tf.Session()
with sess: 
    sess.run(init_op)
    print sess.run(result1)
    print sess.run(result2)
```

result1=11*22

result2=11+22

running results:

484

33